# Tampermonkey doesn't fetch @require using localhost HTTPS static files

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, tampermonkey

### Expected Behavior

In order to ease development i want to serve the necessary TM `@require` files through a localhost HTTP(S) server. I expected these files to be reloaded on each page reload.

### Actual Behavior

The files are fetched from the localhost server when i update the UserScript in the TM editor, however, they are not fetched when a matched URL is loaded. I'm not sure if this is a caching thing by TM or if i'm doing something wrong here.

### Specifications

- FireFox 91.0.2
- TM: 4.13.6136
- OS: Windows 10
- Matched URL: all LinkedIn pages

### Script

To separate concerns in the JS files, the UserScript header is separated from other logic. The necessary files are imported using @required. This is the content of the UserScript file that is pasted in the TM editor:

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name            myName
// @description     myDescription
// @author          robinlarondelle
// @version         0.1
// @namespace       myNameSpace
// @homepage        myHomePage
// @include         *linkedin.com/*
// @icon            https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=linkedin.com
// @grant           window.onurlchange
// @require         https://localhost:3000/public/myScript.user.js
// ==/UserScript==
```

The localhost HTTPS static file server is a Node.JS server with a self signed certificate to enable HTTPS. When using Postman and FireFox after providing my `.pem` file, the server works as expected. If necessary i can provide more details about the server, but i don't think the problem resides here.

### Things to point out:

FireFox prohibits accessing local files from TM (see this [comment](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/347#issuecomment-269039234)). So one alternative to this problem would be to just use Chrome, as it does support accessing local files. However, i want to abstain from using local files because there are multiple developers working on this project. I also don't want to limit development to one specific browser.

The main question/problem is: Why does `@require` from the UserScript header only fetch the required files on Script Save in the TM editor, but not on Page Reload when the URL matches? Is this normal behavior and/or can we turn this off?

Comment: Caching `require/resource` and updating them only occasionally is normal behavior for all userscript managers. You can suggest the author of Tampermonkey to implement an exception for localhost URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Tampermonkey/tampermonkey/issues/1329) on the Tampermonkey repository as well and someone came up with the solution:

Set "Externals" update frequency to "Always". This will fetch the `@require` tag on page reload. This does however not run smoothly and most of the time it will fetch *after* page reload (so you have to reload twice).

Anyways, this solved the problem for me.